# Not able to playback Mux assets in vue.js app

Tags: vue.js, hls.js, mux-video

I'm just testing out [Mux](https://mux.com/). Created an asset - and (as Mux tells me) it plays back fine if the url is just pasted into the adress bar of Edge. No tokens or anything - just the "playback url".

However, when I try to implement it in my app - [as per their instructions](https://docs.mux.com/docs/web-video-playback-1) - I get a black video screen / no content.

I've got hls.js installed via npm and it appears to be working since the console.log in the if-statement produce the expected result. See code below:

```
<video 
    id="minVideo"                     
    controls
    height="auto"
    width="800px"
    class="has-text-centered"
    style="border: 1px solid #000000;"
    >
</video>

<script>
import Hls from 'hls.js';

(function(){
    var url = "https://stream.mux.com/Z014FJxxGXOCIcZGu013900aAGgNoaqDEkDYJu00J00SZ74Q.m3u8";

    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        console.log(url)
        var video = document.getElementById("minVideo");
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource(url);
        hls.attachMedia(video);
    }
})();
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Gave up on this - installed video.js and got it working straight away.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Video</h1>
        <video id="myVideo" controls></video>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import Hls from 'hls.js'
console.log('Hsl', Hls)

export default {
    name:"Video",

    mounted() {
         (function(){
            // Replace with your asset's playback ID
            var playbackId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            var url = "https://stream.mux.com/"+playbackId+".m3u8"
            var video = document.getElementById("myVideo")

            let hls = new Hls()
            hls.loadSource(url)
            hls.attachMedia(video)

        })()
    },

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the example on the hls site worked well, particularly as it has a fallback for when hls is not supported (ios)

https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/#embedding-hlsjs

in my nuxt app, i adpated to this:

```
  mounted() {
    // https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/#embedding-hlsjs
    const videoSrc = `https://stream.mux.com/${this.playbackId}.m3u8`
    // var video = document.getElementById('myVideo')
    const video = this.$refs.video

    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      let hls = new Hls()
      hls.loadSource(videoSrc)
      hls.attachMedia(video)
    } else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
      video.src = videoSrc
    }
  },
```

where `playbackId` is set as a computed value